# How to filter on exact file extension?

Tags: batch-file, wildcard, filenames, file-extension

I have `.las` and `.lasx` files which have the same file name in a `DATA` folder. I am trying to apply processes on the *.las files **only**. But it seems that the wildcard pattern `*.las` also includes *.lasx files:

```
for %%f in ("%DATA_PATH%\*.las") do
```

or

```
lasground -i "%DATA_PATH%\*.las" -merged
```

The parameter before `-merged` is supposed to be the list of my *.las files only, but during my tests it always includes the *.lasx files.

Any idea about how to get all my .las files **without** getting the .lasx ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After providing the documentation and the actual program you are using I would give these two examples a try.

Make a variable with all the file names.

```
@ECHO OFF

for %%G in ("%DATA_PATH%\*.las") do (
    IF /I "%%~xG"==".las" call set list=%%list%% "%%G"
)
lasground -i %list% -merged
```

Make a list of files and use the -lof option.

```
@ECHO OFF

(for %%G in ("%DATA_PATH%\*.las") do (
    IF /I "%%~xG"==".las" echo %%G
)
)>List.txt
lasground -lof List.txt -merged
```

Comment: Well, I was doing something similar, but I then would the need to store the .las result in a list (as I need to give that list as a parameter for mycommand, which will process it all), and I don't know how to do that ... I thougth it would be simpler to find a way to filter this directly. Any idea ?

Comment: @Arkeen without knowing how many files you are merging and what program you are using to merge the files, it would be hard to give you any more constructive feedback.

Comment: Well, mycommand is actually lasground (from LASTolls), doc here : https://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/lasground_README.txt). So far I only want to merge 5 files, but probably more in the future.

Comment: I would assume the command can take multiple file names if it can also use wildcards.  So just build the file list with the for command.  Then execute your command with the file list variable.

Comment: @Arkeen looks like you missed this option: `-lof file_list.txt`

Comment: @Arkeen I have updated my answer. In the future I would advise that you provide all information up front.  There was no reason to obfuscate the program you were using.  The developer of LASTOOLS did create a [Google Group Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/lastools) to ask question.  I always say get your answers from the source first.

Answer (score 2):

The `Where` command is a simpler way to filter this directly, i.e. output only the extension specified:

```bat
@Where "%DATA_PATH%":*.las 2>Nul >"LasOnly.txt"
```

You can then use `"LasOnly.txt"` as input to `lasground` using the `-lof` option as already advised:

```bat
@lasground -lof "LasOnly.txt" -merged
```